# Why try...catch doesn't work when I throw in Promise executor function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, try-catch

I've heard that a Promise executor function is synchronous. If it's true, why can't the exception be caught in `try...catch` block? It doesn't make sense to me.

I don't need the "just use the `.catch` function", I need the theory behind *why* it works like that.

```
try {
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    throw "Error"
  })
}
catch (e) {
  console.error(`try...catch ${e}`);
}
```

Comment: While promise executor function is indeed running synchronously, the errors thrown within it are not handled synchronously - they cause the corresponding Promise to be rejected instead. And `try-catch` around that Promise basically doesn't know anything about 'Promise reject' - unless you use `await`, of course.

Comment: https://bluepnume.medium.com/intentionally-unleashing-zalgo-with-promises-ab3f63ead2fd + https://blog.izs.me/2013/08/designing-apis-for-asynchrony/ on why an async API should be asynchronous. Not *sometimes* asynchronous but other times synchronous.